# Run bundle with sudo in MacOS .app bundle

Tags: mac, zsh, sudo, deployment

I have a MacOS app that I want to deploy as .app bundle. The binary in this bundle is needed to run with root priveleges.

I made launcher zsh script in Contents/MacOS with line `sudo ./MyApp`. I changed property `<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>` to `launcher` in Info.plist. When I execute `open /Applications/MyApp.app` I see that MyApp running from current user, not from root. I even added path to MyApp to sudoers so OS don't ask for password, but still no luck.
How can make MacOS run my binary from root when I execute open `MyApp.app` or from Applications menu?